# Alternative color class after first elements

Tags: jquery

I need to add add a class that will style list items differently. Because I have more than one list on a page and I need to restart styling for each list I decided to look though each list.

```
$('ul.myList').each(function() {
    $('li:visible:even:not(.red, .green)').addClass('newStyle');
});
```

Some of the items are hidden and the top two items in each list need to be skipped.

```
<ul>
    <li class="red">...</li>
    <li class="blue">...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li class="hidden">...</li>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li class="red">...</li>
    <li class="blue">...</li>
    <li class="hidden">...</li>
    <li class="hidden">...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

For some reason it seems that the odd/even count continues from one list to another. What am I missing?

P.S. Here i used .hidden to give an idea, there are actually several different ways those are hidden.

Comment: Your UL elements have no class... Is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector for `li` need to specify a reference point if you want to "restart" the even/odd count.
You can use `.find()` to select descendent elements.

```
$('ul.myList').each(function() {
    $(this).find('li:visible:even:not(.red, .green)').addClass('newStyle');
});
```

The `$(this)` in the above context refers to the particular `ul` you are currently iterating in the `.each()`

Comment: Dah... That was it, thanks! Although my :not seems to be ignored, but that's another issue.